# System.Nullable<System.TimeSpan>' does not contain a definition for 'TotalMinutes'

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datetime, nullable, timespan

Is there an elegant way around this error rather than checking .HasValue in the if() then adding the Value such as DateTimeUtcNow.Value?

```
// Compare nullable date time entity.End with utcnow but only compare up to minute precision
// for time.
//
if ((int)(entity.End - DateTime.UtcNow).TotalMinutes < 0) 
{
   // ASSERT: entity.End < UTCNow (i.e. 12/4/2012 3:56 PM < 12/4/2012 3:57 PM) 
}
```

> Error: System.Nullable' does not contain a
>   definition for 'TotalMinutes'

Answer (score 6):

Personally I'd write this as:

```
if (entity.End > DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1))
{
    ...
}
```

That condition will be false if `entity.End` is null.

I often find that rather than one date/time from another and comparing that with a `TimeSpan` (or whatever type you're using), it's clearer to compute a lower-bound or upper-bound, and compare that with the variable date/time. It certainly works out cleanly in this case.

EDIT: Okay, now that the question's a *little* clearer, I'd write this as:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
DateTime lowerBound = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Hour, now.Minute,
                                   0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
DateTime upperBound = now.AddMinutes(1);
if (entity.End >= lowerBound && entity.End < upperBound)
{
    ...
}
```

I suspect I may still have misunderstood though...

Comment: Very nice (padding for char limit here)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Thx! Definitely much cleaner. However, what I'm trying to do with that nullable date time (entity.End) is compare it against Now but only up to minute precision. Addminutes(1) doesn't seem yield proper results.  Still looking to see what I can tweak to get it to work.

Comment: @JaJ: It's hard to tell what you're trying to achieve, to be honest. If you could give more details and examples in the question, that would really help.

Comment: @JaJ `if (entity.End > new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, 0).AddMinutes(1)) { }`

Comment: @JonSkeet: Hi Jon. I updated the original ask code. Basically I need to compare a nullable datetime with now but only up to minute precision for time (i.e. disregard seconds and milliseconds).

Comment: @JaJ: Okay - it seems to me that the nullable part is somewhat incidental here. See my edit though - hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to create an extension method to access the value in a nullable and propagate nulls:

```
public static TOut? Select<T, TOut>(this T? nullable, Func<T, TOut> func) 
    where T : struct 
    where TOut : struct
{
    return nullable.HasValue ? (TOut?)func(nullable.Value) : null;
}
```

then you can do:

```
if ((entity.End - DateTime.UtcNow).Select(t => t.TotalMinutes) > 1)
{
}
```